# Exporting Hierarchical Telerik RadGrid to Excel

Tags: telerik, export, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid that is hierarchical with parent and child grids.  However, when I call the ExportToExcel() method, only the MasterTableView is exported.  When I call the ExportToExcel() method on the Details table, an error is thrown "RadGrid must be databound before exporting.".  Any ideas how to accomplish this export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik RadGridView does not currently support exporting hierarchy grids to excel. Please review the answer at [this link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/does-exporttoexcelml-support-exporting-child-templates.aspx#1524221) for full details. 
Regards, 
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Expand all inner levels (by setting the HierarchyDefaultExpanded property at each detail level to true) prior to calling the export method, which I think is meaningful solely for the entire grid.